# "list index out of range" error when setting a string variable in for-loop instead of string directly?

Tags: python, json, list

I am just trying to loop through certain letters in a json-message and then extract a new json-message out of it and it doesn't work but it should!

```
json_message = ast.literal_eval( f"{   { 'B': [{'a': 'A', 'f': '1', 'l': '0.00000000'}, {'a': 'B', 'f': '2', 'l': '0.00000000'}, {'a': 'C', 'f': '3', 'l': '0.00000000'}]} }" )

currency = ["'A'", "'C'"] 
for x in range(len(currency)):

    aaa = currency[x]

    print(aaa)
```

gives

```
'A'
```

So, aaa = 'A', right? Therefore, this should work:

```
msg = [y for y in json_message['B'] if y['a'] == aaa]

print(msg[0])
```

but it gives

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because

```
print(msg)

[]
```

However, when I do

```
msg = [y for y in json_message['B'] if y['a'] == 'A']
```

then it works:

```
print(msg[0])
{'a': 'A', 'f': '1', 'l': '0.00000000'}
```

Question: Why doesn't it work and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's interesting, it seems like list comprehension can only works with the variable inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

`aaa` includes the single quotes as part of the string itself. The line that doesn't work is equivalent to

```python
msg = [y for y in json_message['B'] if y['a'] == "'A'"]
```

You can see this if you do `print(repr(aaa))`, which (for most objects) prints the code you would type to get that exact object. So `print(repr('"foo"'))` would print `'"foo"'`, rather than `"foo"`.

To fix it, you can either remove the single quotes from the strings in `currency`, or if those are coming from some code outside your control, pass them through `ast.literal_eval()` as well.